# Finding most common sextuplets in a huge set of numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a matrix 6000x20, containing numbers is range from 1-80. I need to find ALL sextuplets that appear in that matrix. I need the most efficient and fastest solution.
My current solution is by this steps:
1.I take first row from matrix and generate all sextuplets (38600 in one row)
2. I compare each of sextuple with other 5999 rows and count them
3. I write them into a file because my memory gets full pretty fast
4. I take 2nd row and generate all sextuplets and i do all steps again

This algorithm is pretty bad and im aware of it because i have 38600X6000 comparisons and possible file writing, and i have a lots of sextuplets repetition. But i cant know that because i cant use variables of that size.

I need an algorithmic solution so i can write it in matlab/java/c++/python

Comment: Decide for a language to get a concise and correct answer.

Comment: Let it be c++, i guess its fastest

Comment: Its pairs, triplets...sextuplets. I need to find which combination of six numbers is most common

Comment: The problem description seems to be rather incomplete, but I can think of it as of Top-K problem. Top-K is traditionally solved by a tournament algorithm. Also, problem size seems to be really small for 21th century technologies, so a straightforward bruteforce might be appropriate for a practical application.

Comment: Ye, but bruteforcing is lasting for 5 days

Comment: This question belongs to http://programmers.stackexchange.com as you ask for an algorithm

Comment: @WorldSEnder when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 1):

Since the values range from 1-80, the total number of possible sextuplets is "only" a tad over 300 million (300,500,200 to be precise). Since there are only 6000 rows in your matrix, the maximum count for any sextuplet is 6000, so the count will comfortably fit in a two-byte integer (`uint16_t`, assuming that exists in your C++ implementation). Three hundred million two-byte integers total 600 megabytes, which you probably have available.

So a simple algorithm would be to create the count vector, initialized to zeros, and then iterate over all the rows in your matrix; for each row, iterate over the 38,760 sextuplets, and for each sextuplet increment the corresponding count.

The trick is figuring out which element in the count vector corresponds to a given set of six numbers. As it happens, that is not too difficult as long as the numbers in the sextuplet are in order from smallest to largest. (That's not a limitation, since you need to have some canonical order for the sextuplet, and sorted in order is a simple canonical ordering.)

To see how to generate the indices, consider how to (hypothetically) enumerate all 300,500,200 combinations of six integers from the set {1..80}. First, we enumerate the combinations which start with a 1, and continue with five integers from the set {2..80}. Then, we enumerate the combinations which start with a 2, and continue with five integers from the set {3..80}. Then, we enumerate the combinations which start with a 3 and continue with five integers from the set {4..80}. And so on. Inside the enumeration of each starting point, we apply the same algorithm recursively.

Now, let's turn that enumeration on its head. Suppose we have some sextuplet `{a,b,c,d,e,f}`. Let's ask how many sextuplets come *after* that sextuplet?

- First, all sextuplets which start with a value greater than `a`. Since the sextuplets are ordered, if a sextuplet starts with a value greater than `a`, then all of its values are greater than `a`, which means that it is some combination of six values from the set `{a+1..80}`, of which there are <sub>80-a</sub>C<sub>6</sub>.
- Then, there are all sextuplets which start with `a` and continue with a quintuplet whose first value is greater than `b`. By the same logic in the above point, the number of such sextuplets is <sub>80-b</sub>C<sub>5</sub>.
- Then, there are all sextuplets which start with `a,b` and continue with a quartet whose first value is greater than `c`: a total of <sub>80-c</sub>C<sub>4</sub>
- Etc.

So the total number of sextuplets following `{a,b,c,d,e,f}` is precisely:

<sub>80-a</sub>C<sub>6</sub>+<sub>80-b</sub>C<sub>5</sub>+<sub>80-c</sub>C<sub>4</sub>+<sub>80-d</sub>C<sub>3</sub>+<sub>80-e</sub>C<sub>2</sub>+<sub>80-f</sub>C<sub>1</sub>

The interesting about the above equation is that there is no interaction between the six variables. We could compute the value by creating six lookup tables for the values of <sub>80-x</sub>C<sub>i</sub> for values of x from 1 to 80, and values of i from 1 to 6. Then we can compute the (inverse) index of any sextuplets by just doing six lookups and adding the values together. (If we needed to, we could subtract the inverse index from the total number of combinations to get the forward index. But in this case, all we need is a bijection from combinations to integers, and the inverse index will work fine.)

At the end of the algorithm, it will be necessary to turn count indices back into sextuplets. That can be done using the same lookup tables, by doing a succession of binary searches: First, find the value of `a` by binary searching in the lookup table for i==6, then subtract the corresponding index and continue to search the remainder in the lookup table for i==5, etc. (In practice, since the lookup table are small, it might turn out that a linear search is faster than a binary search. It probably doesn't make much difference.)